# Angular Sanctum Session-base Cross Domain CSRF Cookie

Tags: angular, laravel, csrf, fortify, laravel-sanctum

I'm trying to make an SPA app with Angular 10 for front-end and sanctum + Fortify for back-end

I managed to make the login on localhost

but when I'm working with my team we are working on local host network

ex.

```
192.168.43.68:4200 is angular app 

192.168.43.74:8000 is Laravel app
```

I have no idea how to test these app

and I'm looking for correct config for **.env**, **sesssion.php**, **sanctum.php** and **foritfy.php**

or if proxy is need for angular app to automatically Laravel makes the cookies
your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while playing around with the problem I have managed to solve it

to test this app in dev mode you must create a proxy file beside your angular.json
with the name of proxy.conf.json

then inside this file set up the URLs that must be proxied(in my case I want to proxy all URL starting with /api and /sanctum for csrf)

```html
{
    "/sanctum/*": {
        "target": "http://192.168.43.74:8000/",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": ""
        }
    },
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://192.168.43.74:8000/",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/": ""
        }
    }
}
```

then import this proxy in angular.json under Architect->serve->option like this

```html
 "options": {
            "browserTarget": "fuse:build",
             "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
            }
```

then your can run the project with this command

ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json

or for ease of use you can put it in the Package.json in start

"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"

and run your server with npm start